# Saving/loading multiple ArrayLists into one file in Java

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

Currently I have a program that can save and load ArrayLists of type "Variable" from a file. However, I would like to be able to save and load different objects(instances of different classes such as "Variables", "Functions"..etc) from just one file. Here is the code I have now:

```
 public SaveState(){
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("vars.stt"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<Variables> vars = new ArrayList<>();
    vars.add(new Variables("g", 5));
    vars.add(new Variables("f", -3.12));
    try {
        out.writeObject(vars);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public LoadState(){
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("vars.stt"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        //final Object o = in.readObject();
        final ArrayList<Variables> vars = (ArrayList<Variables>) in.readObject();
        System.out.println(vars.toString());
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code only allows me to load one object type from a file. Is there any way to save/load multiple object types in this manner?

Comment: didn't you try making a base class for Functions and Variables and using the array list of type Base Class?

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha Honestly I'm not sure if I would be able to do that, it would require me to refactor a lot of my code (hundreds of lines). Is there another solution.

Comment: No, you just can create some base class(say "ProgramElement"), them just extent the Variables and Functions class from it. No need to refactor the code.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha So if I had classes "Variables", "Functions", and "Lists" how would I extend all 3 from one class?

Comment: Why don't you use Object class as that 'base class'. You can use polymorphism.

Comment: @Arman Still the same way. Just extend the Lists class from ProgramElement I mentioned. Btw, using Object class as the base class is not a good practice, even though it works well.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha Can you add a solution with this implementation? I'm not sure how to extend multiple classes from base class. Sorry

Comment: Change your  ArrayList<Variables> to  ArrayList<Object>, which will store the object. when you get List of object check for like list.get(0) instanceof Variables then cast it and use it..

Comment: Added an answer with a possible class hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a map conataining the arraylists of varaible or functions. Map is good in terms of performance also.

```
    Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<String, List>();
    map.put("variable", arralist1);
    map.put("functions", arralist2);
    map.put("list", arralist3);
```

Comment: So this would work even if the ArrayLists are of different types?

Comment: Yes.  Or you can use generics to make it parameterized.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. It worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Create a class hierarchy like this:

```
//base class. No need to write any content
class ProgramElement {

}

//your variables class
class Variables extends ProgramElement {
    //your code
}

//your functions class
class Functions extends ProgramElement {
    //your code
}

//your lists class
class Lists extends ProgramElement {
    //your code
}
```

Then use an ArrayList of type ProgramElement. Remember **List** here is not your Lists class. It's java's List interface.

```
List<ProgramElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();
elements.add(aFunction); //add function object
elements.add(aList);  //lists object
elements.add(aVariable); //variables object
```

**Note:** You can achieve the same by using a List of type Object. But it is not recommended since it is not a good practice.

Comment: Thank you very much, at first I thought you were telling me to do something along the lines of "class ProgramElement extends Variables, Functions, Lists { }" That is where I got confused. Thank you again.